# hibernate jdpa mysql any list entry within another list query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Using:

- hibernate
- mysql
- spring

assume the current layout

```
Activity (id,etc) [id is primary key]
AcitivityMapper (activityID, targetYearID)  [composite key]
Years (targetYearID, targetYearName) [id primary key, name is unique]
```

I would like to, given a list of "year names", find the activities that can be mapped to at least one of the year names

Extra notes: using the above layout, an activity can be mapped to multiple years

Example:

- Activity (1, bla1)
- Year (1, year1)
- Year (2, year2)
- Year (3, year3)
- Mapper( 1, 1)
- Mapper (1, 2)

If given a list containing "year1" or "year2" i want to get activity 1

How would I do this using an sql query?

---- Hibernate note

My objects would be as follows:

```
@Entity @Table(name="Activity")
class Activity {
 @Id @Column(name="id") private Integer id;
 @ManyToMany @JoinTable(name="ActivityMapper",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id")},inverseJoinColumns{@JoinColumn(name="targetYearID")}) private List<TargetYear> targetYears = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity @Table(name="Years")
class TargetYear {
 @Id @Column(name="targetYearID") private Integer id;
 @Column(name="targetYearName") private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a.id,
   a.etc
FROM years y
JOIN activitymapper am
   ON (y.targetyearid = am.targetyearid)
JOIN activity a
   ON (a.id = am.activityid)
WHERE y.targetyearname IN ('Year1', 'Year2')
```

Taken from: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83678/at-least-one-member-of-a-list-within-another-list-when-querying-over-a-join by @SQB

Answer (score 0):

you can use below native SQL query.

select a.id,a.etc from activity a join activityMapper am on a.id= am.activityID where am.targetYearID IN(select targetYearID from Years y where y.targetYearName= yearName

Comment: this doesn't cater for a list on the opposite side however. Posting a different solution